# Setting argv[0] in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, argv, ps

Is there a way to set `argv[0]` in a Haskell program (say, one compiled with ghc)?

I found the `getProgName` and `withProgName` functions in System.Environment, but it doesn't seem to change what `ps` reports (Ubuntu).

```
import System.Environment

main =
  do name <- getProgName
     putStrLn $ "Hello, my name is " ++ name
     withProgName "other" $ do
       newname <- getProgName
       putStrLn $ "Name now set to " ++ newname
       putStrLn "What is your name: "
       -- allow time to run ps
       ans <- getLine
       putStrLn $ "Pleased to meet you, " ++ ans
```

Comment: There is no reliable and portable way to change what `ps` reports, so I wouldn't be surprised if GHC does not support this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no portable way of doing this, but on Linux 2.6.9 and up the process name can be changed with [`prctl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/prctl) using the `PR_SET_NAME` operation, so we just need a little bit of FFI to use it from Haskell. (It's usually a good idea to check if there are any bindings on Hackage, but in this case I couldn't find any).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Foreign.C

foreign import ccall "sys/prctl.h prctl"
  prctl :: CInt -> CString -> CULong -> CULong -> CULong -> IO CInt

setProgName :: String -> IO ()
setProgName title =
  withCString title $ \title' -> do
    res <- prctl pr_set_name title' 0 0 0
    return ()
  where pr_set_name = 15
```

This seems to work fine for changing the name as seen by `ps`. However, the value returned by `getProgName` appears to be cached when the program starts, so you'll have to combine this with `withProgName` to see the change within your program.

Comment: This seems to only change the name in the output of 'ps -A', 'ps -a' 'ps -d', 'ps -e' and maybe others, whereas 'ps a', 'ps -ef', 'ps f' and probably others still show the original command line arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The program name is fixed at the time the program starts, so any mechanism to change the reported program name will be OS-specific. As far as I know, there's no way to do this with the standard libraries, and a quick search of [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html) doesn't show anything up. I'm not sure there's any way to accomplish this with Linux in the first place, other than re-executing the same program with a different `argv[0]`.