# Access original argv pointer from Haskell

Tags: haskell, ffi

Is it possible to access the original `argv` pointer from within a Haskell `main`?

My use case is that I'd like to remove command-line parameters after the application has started so they can't be read via `ps`. There are a few ways to do this but all require manipulating the original`argv`.

I am able to do this if I write a C wrapper and call `hs_init` from there (afterwards mucking around with `argv` ala [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88665/how-does-ps-know-to-hide-passwords)), but it'd be nicer to do this from Haskell.

Thanks!

PS - this question is different from the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503157/setting-argv0-in-haskell) as the duplicate uses a `prctl` which, as far as I can tell, only lets you change the process name. Further, the duplicate is looking to "set" `argv[0]` whereas I am trying to obtain a mutable reference to the original `argv` used to call the program.

Comment: My initial guess is that it isn't possible from Haskell since there is no `setArgs` function and `getArgs` returns an immutable list.

Comment: Thanks. I've been pouring over the FFI code and came to the same conclusion, but since I'm relatively new to this I didn't know if there was another way.

Comment: This is something I didn't even know was possible 5 minutes ago, so there might be a way, but if there is a way it'll involve some strange corner function in an internal library.  Look in the GHC specific libraries, since it'd likely depend on which compiler you're using.

Comment: @bheklilr this is what I've been doing. There are functions in `System.Environment` but they're not exported. I may end up re-writing some of them for this purpose, but wanted to check-in first. Thanks.

Comment: [Try this](https://gist.github.com/ec78cc20e78479029812).  I'm currently on windows so I don't think I can check it very accurately.  Cygwin's ps doesn't show command line arguments at all, but Process Monitor catches everything that the process does so it records the command line args before you have a chance to overwrite it.  Something along these lines might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @bheklilr hmm, I had something similar to this earlier and that didn't work, neither did yours :(

Comment: If you're on a POSIX system you could 1) transfer all of the command line arguments to the environment, 2) `execve` yourself with no command line args and then 3) cleanse the environment; `execve` is available as `executeFile` in System.Posix.Process

Comment: @amalloy I don't think that's a duplicate. It's close, but it uses a `prctl` which, as far as I can tell, only lets you change the process name.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the `System.Posix.Env.ByteString`[(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0/docs/System-Posix-Env-ByteString.html#v:getArgs) module from the `unix` package.

It contains functions to modify the environment and even though it only provides `getArgs` it shouldn't be difficult to add a `setArgs` function.

Comment: This strategy doesn't seem to work. Try this code [here](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/ec78cc20e78479029812), which is very similar to the `getArgs` method in `System.Posix.Env.ByteString`. Maybe this is related to some lazy evaluation? Not sure.

Comment: hmmm... even if you add `getArgs >>= print` at the end the original args are printed. wonder why that's happening.